# Intellij unused Injects are not detected

Tags: intellij-idea, inject, unused-variables

I am trying to clean my code and delete `@Inject` fields in my classes which are not used. I tried to follow this https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/04/global-unused-declaration-inspection/ in order to achieve this. Somebody seems to have succeeded in making it work in the comments of the link but it didn't work at all for me. As soon as I add @Inject over my fields, there is no warning, even if the injected variable is private and never used !

Is this not supported for some reason or is there somewhere else I need to change the settings ? What I did was to set `private` on the inspection of the fields. I even tried to add an entry point on the `Inject` annotation. Needless to say that nothing of this worked.

Comment: What IntelliJ IDEA version do you use? [Similar issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-121612) was resolved recently. If it happens in [2017.2](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/), please [report a new bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) with the sample project to reproduce.

Comment: Okay well fyi it still doesn't work in 2017.2